# Does JIRA work on Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: jira, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is JIRA supported in GCE? If so, how to make it work?

We have installed 64-bit .bin of JIRA(6.4.1), and opened necessary custom http ports under *Networks*.

Started JIRA as service, but unable to see it work via browser. No error message than, timed out error!

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Note: We are new to Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: You can detail how you have configured network?

Answer (score 3):

Did you enable the http and https services on your instance ? By default the GCE instance does not allow Http and Https traffic, you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The Jira configuration for Google Compute Engine can be tricky. You need to make sure that:

1. The firewall rules under Netowrking allows a connection to Jira HTTP port or the HTTP enables in VM properties
2. The global Networking rules allow TCP traffic on this port
3. The virtual network have routes configured
4. If you use Apache as proxy for Jira (recommended) then make sure Apache is configured to point to the Tomcat port
5. Your Tomcat is configured
6. You have enabled port allocation using setcap utility
7. Your local machine firewall enables the connection (in Red Hat ipconfig is enabled by default and blocks the connections)

As you can see it may be tricky to install Jira on Google Cloud. It may be a good idea to use a deployment service like Deploy4Me to do this quickly and automatically.